# Using malloc and free wrappers

Tags: c, malloc, free

Can somebody suggest how to free the memory allocated inside a function other than main (eg: mymalloc() in the below example)? Does calling free from a different function in the program work? Or, since we allocated memory in myalloc(), do we need to free it inside myalloc() itself?
Please suggest if there is a better way of implementing the below.

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  int * arr = {0};

  foo();
  return 1;
}

void mymalloc(int ** myarr1 ) {
  (*myarr1) = (int*) malloc( sizeof(int)*25 );
  (*myarr1)[3] = 69;
}

void myfree(int ** myarr2 ) {
   if (*myarr2) {
    memset(*myarr2, 0, sizeof(int)*25 );
    free(*myarr2);
}

void foo() {
  int * arr1 = {0};

  mymalloc(&arr1);
  printf("car[3]=%d\n",arr1[3]);
  myfree (&arr1);

  // Check if memory was freed
  if (arr1) {
  printf("ERROR: Memory allocated to arr1 is not freed.");
  exit (1);
  }
}
```

Output:
**ERROR: Memory allocated to arr1 is not freed.**

Comment: `test.c:20: error: ‘arr’ undeclared (first use in this function)`.

Comment: @ulidtko: Thanks. Corrected now. I just typed in the code to give an idea of what I am trying to do.

Comment: BTW, unless you are writing secure code, there is no need to clear memory before using `free`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not necessary to call malloc and free in the same function, but I have some remarks on your code:

1. Why use separate functions?
2. The memset in myfree is useless, the pointer is invalidated anyway.
3. Assigning {0} to the pointers is useless, because malloc will overwrite these anyway.

Comment: @Patrik: Since I will be calling malloc several times in my code, I wanted to keep my main() clean and short, hence separate functions. And my compiler chokes if I don't initialize variables. I updated code with different variable names to be clear about my question. Now, does the above code free the memory allocated to `arr1` in `foo`? Or since the `malloc` was done on `myarr1` in `mymalloc`, do I need to free `myarr1`?

Comment: The post has changed but memsetting memory to some marker value BEFORE  freeing it can be valuable for chasing down overrun bugs.

Comment: @Martin: Thanks Martin. That was the intent I had it there initially. I just removed it so folks can focus on my main question, which I mentioned in response to @Patrik's remarks.

Comment: Yes, your code will free arr1. arr1 and *myarr1 point to the same memory location.

Comment: @Patrik: Thanks for the clarification. Ignore my above (late) question. Now that you confirmed that the above code works as expected, I need to figure out the real reason for memory not being freed up in my code.

Comment: @MemoryLeak : You can find memory locations that are not freed with the memcheck tool of valgrind ( [link](http://valgrind.org/) )

Comment: @Patrik: I added a check in `foo` to see if the memory was actually freed up. I get the error as I mentioned in the OUTPUT above. Any pointers/suggestions?

Comment: @Patrik: While it is true that the initial value of the pointer will be overwritten by the allocation function, some coding standards actually insist on mandatory variable initialization at the point of declaration. I myself consider such requirements to be largely useless, but one might encounter it in actual code pretty often. What is really unnecessary here is the `{}` around `0`. `int *arr = {0};` is exactly the same thing as `int *arr = 0;`. The redundant pair of `{}` can only confuse an unprepared reader.

Comment: @MemoryLeak: Calling `free()` releases the allocated memory but it doesn't clear the contents of the pointer variable. It's your responsibility to not dereference the now-invalid pointer. You might set it to NULL.

Comment: Blastfurnace is correct here, assigning NULL or 0 to *myarr2 will fix this issue

Comment: @Blastfurnace, @Patrik: I did that in my original post. I removed it only to avoid extending the discussion on less important points of this post. I added it back now as the context demanded :-). I am running into the same problem even after memsetting to 0.

Comment: @MemoryLeak : No, we mean setting the pointer to 0 (after the free), not the memory itself: `*myarr2 = 0;`

Answer (score 2):

You can `free` anything you have created with `malloc` anywhere in the program.

Memory allocated with `malloc` comes from the "heap" section of memory, and will persist throughout the lifetime of a program unless released with `free`.

Answer (score 0):

your memory is correctly freed, but a free call does not set the pointer to null, the pointer is still pointing to the ,now invalid, address. If you where to try writing something to arr1 after the free, you would get a segmentation fault, even if arr1 is not pointing to null.

that's why you should always set a pointer to null just after freeing it